# Laravel 5.6 not found error while I make an Api call from postman

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.6

I am trying to access my API function from the postman, But it gives me **404(not found error)**

> Folder structure - app/http/controllers/mycontroller.php

I have added **route in api.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\V1', 'as' => 'api.'], function () {     
    Route::post('/myurl', 'mycontroller@functionName');
});
```

From postman, I am trying to hit the following URLs

- https://myserver.com/api/myurl
- https://myserver.com/api/v1/myurl

These URLs gives me the error 404

Please, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: post your postman screenshot

Comment: It only gives error as:
Not Found
The requested URL /v1/myurl was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: have you checked https settings for postman?

Comment: yes they work for another project

Answer (score 0):

try after removing namespace

Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1'], function () {

Route::post('/myurl', 'mycontroller@functionName'); });

https://myserver.com/api/v1/myurl

Comment: Still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing namespace as said by @nkitku

Or

Move your controller at App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\MyController.php

Comment: Can you test this by direct url in browser changing route from post to get?